# Keep answers in a shiny app form

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very long form that I wanted to "save" a checkpoint, come back later and the questions would still be filled. Is there a way to do it?

Here's an example to illustrate:

**ui**:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Example of a question"),

    # textInput with a name 
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput(inputId = 'text',
                  label = "What's your name?",
                  value = '')
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
         actionButton(inputId = 'save',
                      label = 'Save')
   )
  )
))
```

**server**:

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   observeEvent(input$save, {
      ## Something that saves the input and keeps it there the next time I 
         connect
   })

 })
```

The thing I want to do is, to click in the save button and next time I enter the application, the answer is still there.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html This may help